# Importing MS Access to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ms-access, jet

Currently trying to update an SQL Server database from an Access db, it works importing new records but fails on when I reimport the file and there is a duplicate - in looking for it to insert the row if it's not there (working), but skip if it already exists. The first column has the primary key set.

```vb
Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable
Dim accConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(
   "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='C:\Tester.mdb';User Id=admin; Password=;")
Dim sqlConnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(
   "Data Source=10.75.24.94;Initial Catalog=CTData;User ID=sql;Password=")
Try
    'Import the Access data
    accConnection.Open()
    Dim accDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(
        "SELECT * FROM Import_test", accConnection)
    accDataAdapter.Fill(table)
    accConnection.Close()
    'Export to MS SQL
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        row.SetAdded()
    Next
    sqlConnection.Open()
    Dim sqlDataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(
        "SELECT * FROM Import_test", sqlConnection)
    Dim sqlCommandBuilder As New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter)
    sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = sqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand()
    sqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = sqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
    sqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = sqlCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand()
    sqlDataAdapter.Update(table)
    sqlConnection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    If accConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        accConnection.Close()
    End If
    If sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        sqlConnection.Close()
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("Import failed with error: " &
                    Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &
                    ex.ToString)
End Try
```

The error I'm presented with is:

> Violation of Primary key. Cannot insert duplicate key in object.

Comment: You are not checking for duplicates there. Can't you just delete all the records on SQL Server table, before copying again from Access database?

Comment: If you've imported the data, why are you trying to import it again? Is this part of a test cycle? If so, you'll want to likely `TRUNCATE` your tables first.

Comment: Load into a temp table, then use `insert where not exists`, update and delete  where not exists to update the SQL server table.

Comment: You might consider looking at t-sql [merge statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I have a simple example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Server-bulk-insert-and-22b3c181?redir=0)

Comment: @KarenPayne nice link to your example but I would like to copy the code. Why, oh why, would you post your code as an image???

Comment: @Mary, all you need to do is use the browse code tab, it has full source code that is also downloadable.

Comment: @KarenPayne That is not all you have to do. Tried it. Can't find the code. Don't have hours to search for it. Don't want to download the whole mess. I just want the CommandText. My goodness!

Comment: Don't know why you think it would take hours, I went there, clicked on the browse tab, clicked on the first project on the tree, clicked PersonExporter.vb and there it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove VB from the equation (I like to make things as simple as possible, without over-simplifying it).  You have several options available.

```
INSERT INTO Table
SELECT * FROM #Table xx
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table rs WHERE rs.id = xx.id)
```

Or . . .

```
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE (ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS Expr1
FROM Table
AS Table_1 GROUP BY NAME,ADDRESS,CITY,STATE,ZIP,PHONE,ETC.))
```

There are a lot of other ways to handle this as well.  Is you need to incorporate VB, you can do something like this.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
       Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\your_path\DB.accdb")

       Dim queryResult As Integer
       Dim sqlQRY As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS FROM ESRRegister WHERE ID = '" & IDtxt.Text & "'"
       con.Open()
       cmd.Connection = con
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
       If queryResult > 0 Then
           cmd.CommandText = "insert into ESRRegister (Dt,ID)VALUES ('" & Dttxt.Text & "' , '" & IDtxt.Text & "')"
           queryResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
           MsgBox("Added Successfuly")
       Else

           MessageBox.Show("Already Exists!", "ALI ENTERPRISES", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

       End If
```

Comment: Im guessing i can remove the sqlCommandBuilder, with its update, insert and delete from the code and change the sqlDataAdapter select command and replace it with the first suggestion of "INSERT INTO Table
SELECT * FROM #Table xx
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table rs WHERE rs.id = xx.id)" would that work with some changes? have 4 columns in the table that need to be different before it inserts that perticular row, they are PRODUCT_ID, DATE_TIME, User_Name and ComponentName. If those 4 are already in the table then they need to be ignored.